# Service Worker & Promises Timing Issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to expand on the google docs solution for fetching from the server if the cache is empty (or expired) but am hitting an issue with timing on the promise.

My code is as follows:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    if (event.request.url.indexOf("targetPage") !== -1) {
        const cacheName = 'myCacheName';
        event.respondWith(
            caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
                return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
                    if(response !== undefined){
                        for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
                            if(pair[0] === 'date'){
                                var tokenExpiryDate = Date.parse(pair[1]);
                                var now = Date.parse(Date());
                                if(tokenExpiryDate < now){
                                    return response;
                                }
                                else{
                                    fetch(event.request).then(function(serverResponse) {
                                        cache.put(event.request, serverResponse.clone());
                                        return serverResponse;
                                    })
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        fetch(event.request).then(function(serverResponse) {
                            cache.put(event.request, serverResponse.clone()); return serverResponse;
                        })
                    };
                });
            })
        );
    }
});
```

As a result I get the error:

> resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a
>   Response was passed to respondWith().

I suspect `serverResponse` showing a value is due to the debugger being paused as sometimes I have caught it as being `undefined`:

[image]

The original code from the google docs (which worked fine for me also) is as follows:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    if (event.request.url.indexOf("targetPage") !== -1) {
        const cacheName = event.request.headers.get("myCache");
        event.respondWith(
            caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
                return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
                    return (
                        response ||
                        fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
                            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                            return response;
                        })
                    );
                });
            })
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Some context would be nice. Where is this example you're working from? What is `self`?

Comment: @DavidKnipe question updated with original code from google

Comment: You're missing a `return` keyword in front of the `fetch(…)` call. Don't forget that you *always* need to `return` something!

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions. In fact you haven't given much clue about what your question is about. Stackoverflow is for questions about all sorts of things. This could be vanilla javascript, or it could be some library provided by google, or it could be a library created by some guy who opened a google page to host his documentation. I have no way of knowing. The tags aren't much use either - all we know from tags is that it's about javascript. Please bear this in mind when you post questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by staying as close as possible to the original solution I was able to get it working:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function(event) {
    if (event.request.url.indexOf("targetpage") !== -1) {
        const cacheName = "myCache";
        event.respondWith(
            caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
                return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
                    return (
                        GetCachedResponse(response) ||
                        fetch(event.request).then(function(response) {
                            cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
                            return response;
                        })
                    );
                });
            })
        );
    }
});

function GetCachedResponse(response) {
    if (response !== undefined) {
        for (var pair of response.headers.entries()) {
            if (pair[0] === "token-expires") {
                var tokenExpiryDate = Date.parse(pair[1]);
                var now = Date.parse(Date());
                if (tokenExpiryDate > now) {
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```